# Extreme performance difference when using DataTable.Add

Tags: c#, .net, performance

Take a look at the program below. It's pretty self-explanatory, but I'll explain anyway :)

I have two methods, one fast and one slow. These methods do the exact same thing: they create a table with 50,000 rows and 1000 columns. I write to a variable number of columns in the table. In the code below I've picked 10 (`NUM_COLS_TO_WRITE_TO`).

In other words, only 10 columns out of the 1000 will actually contain data. OK. The *only* difference between the two methods is that the fast populates the columns and *then* calls `DataTable.AddRow`, whereas the slow one does it *after*. That's it.

The performance difference however is *shocking* (to me anyway). The fast version is almost completely unaffected by changing the number of columns we write to, whereas the slow one goes up linearly. For example, when the number of columns I write to is 20, the fast version takes 2.8 seconds, but the slow version takes over a *minute*.

What in the world could possibly be going on here?

I thought that maybe adding `dt.BeginLoadData` would make a difference, and it did to some extent, it brought the time down from 61 seconds to ~50 seconds, but that's still a *huge* difference.

Of course, the obvious answer is, "Well, don't do it that way." OK. Sure. But what in world is causing this? Is this expected behavior? I sure didn't expect it. :)

```
public class Program
{
    private const int NUM_ROWS = 50000;
    private const int NUM_COLS_TO_WRITE_TO = 10;
    private const int NUM_COLS_TO_CREATE = 1000;

    private static void AddRowFast() {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();            
        //add a table with 1000 columns
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_COLS_TO_CREATE; i++) {
            dt.Columns.Add("x" + i, typeof(string));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS; i++) {                
            var theRow = dt.NewRow();
            for (int j = 0; j < NUM_COLS_TO_WRITE_TO; j++) {
                theRow[j] = "whatever";
            }

            //add the row *after* populating it
            dt.Rows.Add(theRow);                
        }
    }

    private static void AddRowSlow() {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        //add a table with 1000 columns
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_COLS_TO_CREATE; i++) {
            dt.Columns.Add("x" + i, typeof(string));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS; i++) {
            var theRow = dt.NewRow();
            //add the row *before* populating it
            dt.Rows.Add(theRow);

            for (int j=0; j< NUM_COLS_TO_WRITE_TO; j++){
                theRow[j] = "whatever";
            }                
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        AddRowFast();
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);

        sw.Restart();
        AddRowSlow();
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);

        //When NUM_COLS is 5
        //FAST: 2754.6782
        //SLOW: 15794.1378

        //When NUM_COLS is 10
        //FAST: 2777.431  ms
        //SLOW 32004.7203 ms

        //When NUM_COLS is 20
        //FAST:  2831.1733 ms
        //SLOW: 61246.2243 ms
    }
}
```

**Update**

Calling `theRow.BeginEdit` and `theRow.EndEdit` in the slow version makes the slow version more or less constant (~4 seconds on my machine). If I actually *had* some constraints on the table, I guess this might make sense to me.

Comment: I think explanation is pretty easy. When `DataRow` is outside the table, changing data doesn't trigger any checks/verifications/notifications etc. For more precise explanation I'd look into `DataRow`s column value setter code...

Comment: @Dennis, but I thought the purpose of BeginLoadData was to "Turns off notifications, index maintenance, and constraints while loading data." Also, it seems like something being 30 *times* slower is a pretty big difference.

Comment: Also, what seems strange to me is that the number of columns in the table affects the run-time. That is, if I update 10 columns and there only *are* 10 columns, then it runs perfectly fine. So, what is .NET doing with all those columns that I'm never touching? Are events firing on those too? Seems weird.

Comment: @aquinas: there's no call to `BeginLoadData` in your sample. Besides, documentation says, that "Use BeginLoadData in conjunction with LoadDataRow and EndLoadData." Looks like it works in very special scenario.

Comment: Right, like I said above, when I did add BeginLoadData it cut off about 10 seconds off the 60 seconds.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When attached to table, much more work is being done to record and track the state on every change.

For example, if you do this,

```
theRow.BeginEdit();

for (int j = 0; j < NUM_COLS_TO_WRITE_TO; j++)
{
   theRow[j] = "whatever";
}

theRow.CancelEdit();
```

Then in `BeginEdit()` , [internally](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/DataRow.cs,2996b23128ec418c) it's taking a copy of the contents of the row, so that at any point, you can rollback - and the end result of the above is an empty row again without `whatever`. This is still possible, even when in `BeginLoadData` mode. Following the path of`BeginEdit` *if attached to a DataTable*, eventually you get into [DataTable.NewRecord()](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/DataTable.cs,a0c0c876c804d462) which shows that it is just copying each value for every column to store the original state incase a cancel is needed - not much magic here. On the other hand, if not attached to a datatable, not much is happening in `BeginEdit` at all and it is exited quickly.

`EndEdit()` is similarly pretty heavy (when attached), as here all the constraints etc are checked (max length, does column allow nulls etc). Also it fires a bunch of events, explictly frees storage used incase the edit was cancelled, and makes available for recall with `DataTable.GetChanges()`, which is still possible in `BeginLoadData`. Infact looking at source all `BeginLoadData` seems to do is turn off constraint checking and indexing.

So that describes what `BeginEdit` and `EditEdit` does, and they are completely different when attached or not attached in terms of what is stored. Now consider that a single `theRow[j] = "whatever"` you can see on the indexer setter for [DataRow](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/DataRow.cs,2b12751a7855832d%20DataRow) it calls `BeginEditInternal` and then `EditEdit` on every single call (if it is not already in an edit because you explicitly called `BeginEdit` earlier). So that means it's copying and storing every single value for each column in the row, every time you do this call. So you're doing it 10 times, that means with your 1,000 column DataTable, over 50,000 rows, it means it is allocating 500,000,000 objects. On top of this there is all the other versioning, checks and events being fired after every single change, and so, overall, it's much slower when the row is attached to a DataTable than when not.

Comment: Good answer. Yeah, the call to NewRecord is definitely a killer.